# Can I create millions of queues in RabbitMQ server?

Tags: memory, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, message

I have installed rabbitmq in a t3.large type of ec2 instance.I want to create a single queue for each user in the rabbitmq. Is is possible and if yes, what configuration is needed? How much memory or storage would I need to create 1 millions queue?

Answer (score -1):

This is not the best way to use it.
RabbitMQ is designed for B2B communication it can handle thousands of queues but millions are too much.

If you are looking for a chat system maybe you need to use the XMPP protocol.